# Joomla deleted articles visible

Tags: joomla

I have deleted some articles in Joomla (1.7). They are invisible in article manager, but are visible on the site. How can I delete them completely? As I see, the "Super User" account even hasn't permissions to edit them (no edit icon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably logged in as super admin on the frontend. That way you can still see articles which are in the trash (not fully deleted). If you want do delete them for good, switch to the trash view and delete them.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I want.